# opencv detecting website form image for certain icon to determine the field

Tags: python, selenium, opencv

trying to use opencv on python with this as opening

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("image2.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for contour in contours:
    # text field
    if aspect_ratio > 2 and aspect_ratio < 9 and h > 20:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('canny', edges)
cv2.imshow("results", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

manage to detect the text field, but some text field has certain icons on the right hand side to indicates types of field such as drop down, or date/time or even spyglass or spectacles to indicates that this field has custom fields to search

[image]

[image]

[image]

i would like to know how can i detect and decide what type of field is this by checking the icons on the right side

Comment: this should be done using DOM information from the browser (browser automation, web automation, selenium, ...), not by scraping a screenshot. what do you say?

Comment: yea i am aware of it, but just wondering if we can do it with opencv?

Comment: yes. generally, you're asking for "object detection". specifically, very specifically for specific screen resolutions (and browser zoom settings), this can be solved with opencv's template matching. look into **pyautogui**. it's made for beginners.